# WSL install invalid command line option

Tags: containers, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I want to install an Ubuntu image in WSL.

But, I get a error when running `wsl --install`:

> Invalid command line option: --install

I am using windows 10 education, version 20H2 OS Build 19042.867.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please be aware that one of the main criteria for questions on this site is that they be regarding *"specific coding, algorithm, or language problems."* Your question would likely be better suited for [Super User](https://superuser.com), but please be sure to familiarize yourself with that site's rules for posting as well.  I'd recommend deleting it here and moving it over to Super User before the mods close it.  It won't count "against" your rep if you do it yourself before downvotes.

Comment: But short answer -- The `wsl --install` option is only available in Windows Insider (OS build 20262 or higher).  For now, please follow the ["Manual Installation Steps"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10#manual-installation-steps), the *last* of which is to install a distribution from the Store.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are attempting to work from Windows Insider documentation, which is not meant for the general public, and it says so. WSL/WSL2 is a fast-moving target.

Most people should use the Microsoft Store to install WSL / WSL2. Search for Ubuntu. Several choices will be displayed. Pick the one [simply called Ubuntu](https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9NBLGGH4MSV6), not Ubuntu 20.04 LTS or whatever. The Ubuntu package is kept current.

VSCode has [current instructions for installing Ubuntu](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl-tutorial), then VSCode. You don't have to install VSCode.

Comment: Quite the opposite, actually.  The `wsl --install` option is too *new* for the OP..  It's only available on Windows Insider builds at the moment, but it will become the preferred way of enabling WSL.  Note also that WSL itself *cannot* be installed from the Store.  You can install a *distribution* from the Store, but you must first install/enable WSL (and preferably WSL2).

Comment: Following the instructions I provide will work for the general public.

Comment: The instructions you *linked to* will work, but they are not the most current, and they will soon be the "outdated instructions."  The instructions for installing WSL that Microsoft keeps up to date are [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10).  Regardless, your statement that "*Most people should use the Microsoft Store to install WSL / WSL2"* is completely incorrect.  You absolutely cannot install WSL/WSL2 from the Microsoft Store.  You can only install a *distribution* from the Store *after* installing WSL/WSL2 manually per either of the instructions we linked to.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the linux distributions that can be installed are listed in **Windows PowerShell**:

```bash
wsl --list --online
```

This command returns a list of linux distributions that can be installed as follows:

```bash
NAME                                   FRIENDLY NAME
Ubuntu                                 Ubuntu
Debian                                 Debian GNU/Linux
kali-linux                             Kali Linux Rolling
Ubuntu-18.04                           Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
Ubuntu-20.04                           Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Ubuntu-22.04                           Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
OracleLinux_7_9                        Oracle Linux 7.9
OracleLinux_8_7                        Oracle Linux 8.7
OracleLinux_9_1                        Oracle Linux 9.1
openSUSE-Leap-15.5                     openSUSE Leap 15.5
SUSE-Linux-Enterprise-Server-15-SP4    SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 15 SP4
SUSE-Linux-Enterprise-15-SP5           SUSE Linux Enterprise 15 SP5
openSUSE-Tumbleweed                    openSUSE Tumbleweed
```

A version name to be installed is selected and the installation is done with the `-d` parameter:

```bash
wsl --install -d Ubuntu-22.04
```

#### Resources

- [Install Linux on Windows with WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install)
- [Basic commands for WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/basic-commands)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you follow the official instructions:
https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/wsl/install

Crucial is the Windows version: For Windows 10, it should be version 2004 or higher (Build 19041 or higher). Windows 11 should work with all versions.

Older versions need to follow the manual installation procedure: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual